# Spark converts pandas date time datatype to bigint

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a `pandas` data frame called `pd_df`. Below are the data types.

```
pd_df.dtypes


id                    int64
TEST_TIME             datetime64[ns]
status                object
Pkg                   object
test_type             object
test_name             object
test_id               int64
test_value            float64
test_times            int64
desc                  object
test_source           object
GP                    float64
dtype: object
```

Now I want to convert this `pd_df` to a `spark` data frame.

I have done like below.

```
spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd_df)
```

I was able to create the `spark_df` successfully. But the data types are not matching my requirement

Required data types of spark data frame.

```
DataFrame[id: int, test_time: timestamp, status: string, pkg: string, test_type: string, test_name: string, test_id: int, test_value: double, test_times: int, desc: string, test_source: string, GP: double]
```

What I got is below

```
DataFrame[id: bigint, test_time: bigint, status: string, pkg: string, test_type: string, test_name: string, test_id: bigint, test_value: double, test_times: bigint, desc: string, test_source: string, GP: double]
```

How can I achieve the result I want

Comment: Please post a sample of your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
 spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd_df).withColumn('TEST_TIME1', unix_timestamp(col('TEST_TIME').cast("string"), "MM-dd-yyyy hh mm ss").cast("timestamp")).drop('TEST_TIME')
```

Also replace "MM-dd-yyyy hh mm ss" to the format of your timestamp. Suppose your timestamp is like 12012017 for 1st Dec 2017, the format will be "mmddyyyy"

Comment: @Vinoth Chinnasamy I have tried your code Got the below exception `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'unixtimestamp(TEST_TIME,MM-dd-yyyy hh mm ss)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires (string or date or timestamp) type, however, 'TEST_TIME' is of bigint type.;"`